# Let $ \mathbb{N}$, $a \in \mathbb{N} \to a+1 \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: natural-numbers

I need to prove the following:

"Let $ \mathbb{N}$, if $a \in  \mathbb{N} \to a+1 \in  \mathbb{N}$"

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, what is your definition of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Also define $+$, please.

Comment: @Garnak Olegovitc this could be a part of the axiomatic definition of natural numbers

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc Well, you have nothing to prove then, simply accept that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually  something to prove here.  $a+1$ is defined in the Peano axioms as $a+S(0)=S(a+0)=S(a)$.  Hence, if $a\in\mathbb{N}$, $a+1=S(a)\in \mathbb{N}$.

We can go further; $a+2=a+S(1)=S(a+1)=S(S(a))$.  Hence, if $a\in \mathbb{N}$, $a+2=S(S(a))\in \mathbb{N}$.  In fact, for any specific $k$, we can equally prove that if $a\in \mathbb{N}$ then $a+k\in \mathbb{N}$.